# Change where stack "works" when cloning repositories or building

Tags: haskell-stack

On my machine I have a relatively small (4GB) /tmp filesystem (`tmpfs` mounted as `noexec`).

When building, stack boths tries to clone some dependencies which are specified as repositories, and also to build artefacts in this `/tmp` FS.

I can always remount as `exec` and then put it back to `noexec` later (I do this a lot for stack) but the resizing is more annoying. Is there a way to specify where `stack` does its work? I couldn't find one in the usage.